# Application Speech to text..i.e, audio input from uart to the text output

Tags: c#

Is there any windows application which takes audio input from uart and  give text output

I need an application which take audio input from UART and gives the output into text format.

I am looking for speech to text i.e., identify any speech in the audio input, transcribe that to text output –

Comment: What sort of text output, exactly? This question doesn't have nearly enough details to make it answerable. Try breaking it down into smaller problems, then try and solve those. If you have difficulties, ask specific questions about the individual problems you're having

Comment: The output in normal text(word) format.

Comment: I can quite easily write you an application which takes serial input, ignores it, and outputs "Divya Divya Divya". Presumably that's not what you want though...

Comment: The output in normal text(word) format. Actually i need an windows application which can perform the same. I need to integrate the code form my embeeded device to PC. The frontend application UART data as input and display the same as text data. For example i speak " Hello Divya what r u doing" it should be sent through the uart then The same should be dispalyed in text document.

Comment: Right, so you've looking for text-to-speech? I.e. identify any **speech** in the audio input, transcribe that to text, and output that?

Comment: I am looking for speech to text i.e.,  identify any speech in the audio input, transcribe that to text output

Comment: Right, it would have been very helpful to put this in your question!

Comment: Hello i edited my question in that way accordingly. Can u please help me out how to get the expected result.